# Caml Query - ExecuteQuery() doing Nothing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, silverlight

I'm trying to read the contents of Sharepoint List 'pfa' using Silverlight 5 and the following VB code. I am geting diagnostic pop-up windows 1-5 but then that's it and nothing further happens. Sharepoint Foundation is running on the local machine.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Documents
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows.Shapes
Imports sp = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Partial Public Class MainPage
Inherits UserControl
Public Class Person
    Public Property PersonName As String
    Public Property PersonRole As String
    Public Property PersonLength As String
End Class

Private Sub UserControl_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As        System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Using ctx As New sp.ClientContext("http://localhost")
        MessageBox.Show("1")
        'Dim ctx As sp.ClientContext = sp.ClientContext.Current

        Dim _List As sp.List = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("pfa")
        MessageBox.Show("2")
        'Dim _Query = sp.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery

        Dim _Query As New sp.CamlQuery()
        _Query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='FullName' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>"

        MessageBox.Show("3")
        Dim _ListItemCollection As sp.ListItemCollection = _List.GetItems(_Query)
        MessageBox.Show("4")
        ctx.Load(_ListItemCollection)
        MessageBox.Show("5")
        ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("6")
        Dim _People As New List(Of Person)
        MessageBox.Show("Just Before Loop")
        For Each _ListItem As sp.ListItem In _ListItemCollection
            Dim _Person As New Person
            _Person.PersonName = _ListItem.FieldValues("FullName")
            _Person.PersonRole = _ListItem.FieldValues("Role")
            _People.Add(_Person)
            MyOutput.Text += _Person.PersonName & vbLf & _Person.PersonRole
        Next

    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: To get more details about the exception, You should use try catch block. Update your question with the exact exception details to get better answers

Comment: try accessing field values like _ListItem.("FullName")